# pyinstaller downloaded using pip not working after installation

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYgBB.png)

I'm trying to install a module called pyinstaller from pip to make .py files into an executable, but can't run it from command prompt. Any ideas as to why it doesn't work or workarounds with other applications that serve the same purpose?

Answer (score -1):

try changing directory to where python location is and try installing again
i.e C:\Users--------------------\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39> pip install pyinstaller

Comment: I did what you said and all the requirements were there already